# Proof verification related to reflexive

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

This is one question I'm solving from Velleman's `How to Prove` book:

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets, and let $F = \{f \mid f : A \to B\}$. Also, suppose $R$ is a relation on $B$, and define a relation $S$ on $F$ as follows:
>
> $S = \{(f,g) \in F \times F \mid \forall x \in A((f(x), g(x)) \in R)\}$
>
> Justify your answers to the following questions with either proofs or counterexamples:
>
> a) If $R$ is relexive, must it be the case that $S$ is reflexive ?

Now this is my proof:

Suppose $R$ is reflexive. Let $f$ be an arbitrary element in $F$. Since
$f \in F$ and $f$ is a function it follows that $\exists! y \in
B((x,y) \in f)$ for an arbitrary $x \in A$. Since $R$ is reflexive, we
know that $\forall b \in B((b,b) \in R)$. Using universal
instantiation, we get $(y,y) \in R$. So, $\forall x ((f(x),f(x))) \in
R$. From the definition of $S$, it follows that $(f,f) \in S$. Since
$f$ was arbitrary it follows that $F$ is reflexive.

Is this proof correct ? I'm interested to know if the writing style
can be made better ?

Specifically this line makes me nervous: **"Using universal
instantiation, we get $(y,y) \in R$"**. Can that be expressed more clearly ?

Comment: The instantiation to $y$ feels a bit odd, because the previous occurrence of $y$ is bound by the $\exists!y$.  It might be clearer to put something like this: "since $R$ is reflexive, therefore $(fx,fx)\in R$ for all $x\in A$".

Comment: E.g.... "Suppose $f:A\to B$.  The reflexivity of $R$ implies that $(f(x),f(x))\in R$ for all $x\in A$.  But then $(f,f)\in S$ by the specification of $S$.  Since $f$ was arbitrary, therefore $S$ is reflexive."

Comment: @mmw Thanks, is introducing a new variable instead of $y$ more clear ?

Comment: In a formal proof, a quantifier $\exists y \ldots$ (or $\exists !y$ or whatever) doesn't affect the meaning of $y$ in subsequent lines.  But natural language is a bit more relaxed about this.  So you might replace the formal quantifier $\exists !y$ with "there's a unique $y$ such that...."  However, this still makes it hard for the reader to remember that $y$ depends on $x$.  So what you might try, in this case, is to write "there's a unique $y$ such that..., call it $f(x)$"; the last bit would be justified by the first part.